# Conditional statement to check if an array is empty with angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have this function:

```
$scope.doPaste = function(destination) {                            
   if ($scope.selectCopy.ids != []) {
       console.log("will copy");
       $scope.CopyFiles(destination);
   }
   if ($scope.selectMove.ids != []) {
       console.log("will move");
       $scope.MoveFiles(destination);
   }                                
};
```

In my app, `$scope.selectMove.ids` and `$scope.selectCopy.ids`  can't be both non-empty. I mean for example when  `$scope.selectMove.ids` is non-empty `$scope.selectCopy.ids` is empty.

My problem is that in the console, I always see both will copy and will move.

Comment: You better check `.length` property!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note `[] != []` return `true` (because they are different objects).

You should use `length` to check whether an array is empty.

```
if($scope.selectCopy.ids.length > 0){
     console.log("will copy");
     $scope.CopyFiles(destination);
}
```

Comment: Here is a good reference for what does and does not resolve to true: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/boolean.html

Comment: I think the code must be bullet proof, so should right `if(angular.isObject($scope.selectCopy.ids) && $scope.selectCopy.ids.length > 0) { }`

Answer (score 6):

I think you should check by `angular.isObject()` which would return true if it is an object.

```
$scope.doPaste = function(destination) {
   if (angular.isObject($scope.selectCopy.ids) && $scope.selectCopy.ids.length > 0) {
       console.log("will copy");
       $scope.CopyFiles(destination);
   }

   if (angular.isObject($scope.selectMove.ids) && $scope.selectMove.ids.length > 0){
       console.log("will move");
       $scope.MoveFiles(destination);
   }                               
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to check for null or undefined values.

```
$scope.doPaste=function(destination) {
   if ($scope.selectCopy.ids && $scope.selectCopy.ids.length > 0) {
       console.log("will copy");
       $scope.CopyFiles(destination);
   }
   if ($scope.selectMove.ids && $scope.selectMove.ids.length > 0) {
       console.log("will move");
       $scope.MoveFiles(destination);
   }                               
};
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to use `if else` condition:

```
if (empty){
  console.log('empty');
}else{
  console.log('not empty');
}
```

in your code. it is some like this:

```
$scope.doPaste=function(destination) {
   if ($scope.selectCopy.ids && $scope.selectCopy.ids.length > 0) {
       console.log("will copy");
       $scope.CopyFiles(destination);
   }
else  {
       console.log("will move");
       $scope.MoveFiles(destination);
   }                               
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure it's an Array with at least one element inside, make a small function for checking that. ( maybe you'll want to extend that check later )

```
var isNonEmptyArray = function(ar){
  return Array.isArray(ar) && (ar.length > 0);
};

$scope.doPaste=function(destination){

   if( isNonEmptyArray($scope.selectCopy.ids) ){
     console.log("will copy");
     $scope.CopyFiles(destination);
   }
   if( isNonEmptyArray($scope.selectMove.ids) ){
     console.log("will move");
     $scope.MoveFiles(destination);
    }
};
```

Also avoid the weak `!=` operator, use the strict one `!==`.

And comparing to `[]` is not helpful, `[]` will always return a new Array.